# Examples of FullCalendar event adding and updating

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, fullcalendar

I have been looking at the FullCalendar documentation.

From what I gather, the calendar grabs data from a source by going to its url with start and end params and expecting json in return. That's fine, the examples show that.

However what is not as clear is how updating works.

Take for example, event drop http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/

How should I deal with this in terms of updating my DB. Should I do an ajax call to `Update.aspx?id=event.id....`

Is this how I should be doing my updates?

Also, I am wondering about the revert func. There are 2 reasons I want this:
If my ajax call fails, if my ajax call returns db update failed. How can I pass the revert

func along to say

```
: success(data) {
}
```

What would be great is if anyone has an example with ajax calls in each required event. The serverside stuff I have no trouble doing, I'm just not clear what is proper to update in terms of which ajax calls I should make to my site.

Thanks

Comment: You would have to call your AJAX method to update the DB.  On failure, you can call a method "refresh" or "refreshEvents" (in the documentation) to refresh the events for the current view, and reset it to how it was before, as a workaround.  That's all I can provide, which is why I'm adding it as a comment.

Comment: This has a full example with updating: http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your ajax call for update some event and after that just refresh calendar:

```
eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
    var id = event.id.toString();
    var start = (event.start.getTime()/1000).toString();
    var end = (event.end.getTime()/1000).toString();
    url = '/some/function/for/update/'+id+'/'+start+'/'+end+'/';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(){
            $('#id_of_calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
            #generate some message here
        },
        error: function(){
            $('#id_of_calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
            #generate some message here
        }
    });
},
```